# How do I integrate code to connect Zapier to Webflow?

Tags: javascript, zapier, webflow

I'm trying to connect some API data to a Webflow site in order to make it generate Collection Items. I believe that I have the data in the correct format (objects inside an array) and I just need to connect it somehow to Webflow, since I already have set up the fields in there. I believe that Zapier does the job, I just don't know exactly how.

I tried to map it using one field but was unsuccessful.
https://prnt.sc/p27lve
https://prnt.sc/p27nuy

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to run the "callback" predefined by Zapier and test it before moving on because the test is what makes the items populate on the action side.

Comment: FWIW, it's easier (and clearer) to organize this code using `await` instead of promises. Glad you got it working though!